# Eclipse - Changing the API Keys in string.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, string, android

I am new to android app development and I have got the code of an app which I am modifying. For testing purposes I was asked to change the API keys in the string.xml as the current ones are those of the original developer.

How exactly do I do this?
And where exactly is string.xml?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`string.xml` is a resource bundle, you will find it in `res/values`, inside your android project.

It looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="api_key">your_api_key</string>
</resources>
```

Simply edit the file, change your key and save it. Reinstall the app and it will take into account the new key.

Comment: You tell me :) It's your app.

Comment: What API are you talking about ?

Comment: <string name="api_key">your_api_key</string> What would your_api_key be? and how would I get them?

Comment: These keys PUBLISH_API_KEY and DEFAULT_API_KEY in the string.xml

Comment: Yes but how could I guess the value ! You are not answering my question, what API, what does this API do ?

Answer (score 0):

`string.xml` is a "Resource" folder - so it should be located in the `res` folder in a subfolder named `values`

Once you've found the file, many third party "plug-ins" or libraries use this file to set developer specific data. For example, Google Analytics may assign you an ID like "UA-12345678-9". So then you hard cade that value where ever you need it in your app.

But then you can have problems, like if the ID changes, your app is transferred to another company, you need multiple ID's, etc. Many times, these things never happen. However, you might plan for them by putting the ID in a single place, like `strings.xml` with an entry like this:

```
<string name="googleAnalyticsID">UA-12345678-9</string>
```

So, if you've been asked to "change the API keys" then first you need to get your own (go to the API provider and sign up). Then look at their installation instructions and figure out what their key looks like and what it might be called. Then check your `strings.xml` for an old key to replace with your brand new one!

Comment: Thanks I've located the file now how do I change the API keys to suit my development machine and eclipse?

Comment: I edited my response based on your comment here and comments on the question.

Answer (score 0):

The strings.xml file is here directory res->values->strings.xml. If you are using eclipse you can enter in fast using. strings.xml is something like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>

         <string name="app_name">MyApplication</string>
         <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
         <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
         <string name="title_activity_splash_screen">SplashScreen</string>
   </resources>
```

So you need to find the rows with keys you are interested in and change the values between<><>

```
   <string name="key">value</string>
```